# short read on HDFS

Tags: c, hadoop, hdfs

I have a file (~.9GB) that I am trying to read with buffer size of 1MiB, it results in short read of 65536 bytes.

```
bash-4.2$ hadoop fs -ls /x/F1
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs supergroup  996147200 2021-10-25 13:56 /x/F1
bash-4.2$
```

To narrow down, I have a simple sample code below.

```
void readtest()
{

        hdfsFS fs = hdfsConnect("default", 0);
        const char* readPath = "/x/F1";
        hdfsFile readFile = hdfsOpenFile(fs, readPath, O_RDONLY |O_CREAT, 0, 0, 0);
        if(!readFile) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s for reading!\n", readPath);
          exit(-1);
        }
        char* buffer = malloc(1048576);
        int count  = hdfsRead(fs, readFile, (void*) buffer, 1048576);
        printf("\n count on read %d \n", count);
}

bash-4.2$ ./sample
count on read 65536
bash-4.2$
```

I then used the native blocksize api , the blocksize turns out to be 128MB , however read still returns 64K.

```
void readtest()
{

        hdfsFS fs = hdfsConnect("default", 0);
        const char* readPath = "/x/F1";
        hdfsFile readFile = hdfsOpenFile(fs, readPath, O_RDONLY |O_CREAT, 0, 0, 0);
        if(!readFile) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s for writing!\n", readPath);
          exit(-1);
        }
        int blocksize  = hdfsGetDefaultBlockSizeAtPath(fs, readPath);
        printf("\n blocksize %d \n", blocksize);
        char* buffer = malloc(blocksize);
        int count  = hdfsRead(fs, readFile, (void*) buffer, blocksize);
        printf("\n count on read %d \n", count);
}

bash-4.2$ ./sample
blocksize 134217728
count on read 65536
bash-4.2$
```

why such a behaviour ? any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

A typical (and default) block size used by HDFS is 128 MB. Thus, an HDFS file is chopped up into 128 MB chunks, and if possible, each chunk will reside on a different DataNode.

If you want to change the default block size, you must be configured it manually in `hdfs-site.xml`. So change the NameNode configuration file to set the HDFS block size, and add or modify the following in the `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/hdfs-site.xml`. Block size is provided using the number of bytes. This change would not change the block size of the files that are already in the HDFS. Only the files copied after the change will have the new block size. So you need to copy it again to take affect.

```
<property> 
    <name>dfs.block.size<name> 
    <value>134217728<value> 
    <description>Block size<description> 
<property>
```

However, your `count` variable is the return value of `hdfsRead`. It returns the number of bytes actually read, which can be less than than the length of the buffer if the end of the file is reached during the read.
It seems you limited by a maximum value in your client code. The maximum length of the buffer in `hdfsread` is the maximum size of `tSize`. Check if `tsize` is `uint16_t` you can read maximum 65535 bytes each time. Check the length of `tSize` by `sizeOf(tSize)`.

Also the default packet size for clients to write in HDFS is 65535, so try to do not open file in write mode and just use `O_RDONLY` to see the effect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but sizeOf(tSize) = 4 . Also, I have used O_RDONLY in the sample code attached.

Comment: You also use O_CREAT. Remove it to see the effect.

Comment: same behavior without O_CREAT.